# Can emails sent from my deleted Google/Gmail account be read?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I want to know if I can still read emails sent from my deleted Google/Gmail account in Gmail? Like say I sent an email to another Gmail account and deleted the account that sent the email. Can I still read the email from the deleted Google account in my Gmail account? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an email account the people who you sent email to can still read the email. This is because the message now exists in their email system.

This is true no matter who runs the email systems. They can be a web based mail system (Gmail, yahoo...) or a computer based email system like outlook.

What is lost when a email account is closed/deleted is the contents in that mailbox. You would not have access to the messages received to that account. You also would have access to the log of messages that were sent.

Answer (score 0):

> eg, You sent an email to another Gmail account and deleted the account that sent the email.

1. emailA account sent out an email to emailB account
2. If the email was sent sucessfully, the email is already in emailB account
3. now emailA account is deleted
4. the email is still in emailB account

So the answer is YES. You can still read the email from the deleted Google account in your other non-deleted Gmail account